# Redirect to route with Apache .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I want to redirect from my .htaccess to a specific route (i use Zend Framework but it's the same for every framework i guess).

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshot/%1? [NC,L]
```

This does not work.
Note: the `snapshot`folder does not exists.

But if i replace the last line by :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-site.com/snapshot/%1? [NC,L]
```

It works...
The second works but the redirect url is visible, and i don't want that.

What can i do for make the first example working?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it does not require mod_rewrite. You have to edit your index.php a little bit. Just after `$application->bootstrap ();` and before `$application->run ();` add this snippet.

```
$application->bootstrap ();

if (preg_match ('~_escaped_fragment_=(.*)~', $_SERVER ['QUERY_STRING'], $match))
{
    $frontcontroller = $application->getBootstrap()->FrontController;
    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http('http://your.site.com/controller/'.$match[1]);
    $frontcontroller->setRequest($request);
}

$application->run ();
```